# SQL error when using outer grouping result to 'IN' operator in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query which tries to use outer aggregation result as an input of subquery (in that case `in` statement):

```
select 
 COUNT(DISTINCT individual_id) as visitors,
 (select 
   (case when 
     SUM(case when cr2.isConverted = true then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
     then 1 else 0 end) as conv from campaigns_reporting as cr2 where 
     cr2.id in (DISTINCT cr1.id) group by individual_id) as conversions
     from campaigns_reporting as cr1 where
     isinholdback = false  and
    occurredat between '2018-02-25T18:00:00.000Z' and '2018-03-04T17:59:59.000Z' and
    customer_id = '1'
 group by campaign_id, isinholdback
```

I am getting following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"
>
> LINE 5: ... from campaigns_reporting as cr2 where cr2.id in (DISTINCT
>   c...
>                                                                ^

**Note: I'm using postgresql.**

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Your query really makes no sense.  You can start by simplifying it . . . to anything that is syntactically correct.  You could also ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, and ask for help on that.

Comment: may be you are right, I'll try to ask another question but still I would love to find an answer on that question. you can have another way to solve the problem but that doesn't mean you can't make current query to work. It can be a good learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your query cannot be done. cr1 cannot use in the select the id because it's not included in the group by. So try this:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT individual_id) as visitors, 
   (case when sum(cr3.conv) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as conversions
   from campaigns_reporting as cr1
   inner join 
   (select id, (case when SUM(case when cr2.isConverted = true then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as conv 
   from campaigns_reporting  as cr2 
   group by id) as cr3 on cr1.id= cr3.id
where isinholdback = false
and occurredat between '2018-02-25T18:00:00.000Z' and '2018-03-04T17:59:59.000Z'
and customer_id = '1'
group by campaign_id, isinholdback
```